# Inconsistent ENOENT on npm rebuild looking for serverless

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, serverless-framework

**Context**

I have a Lambda function which uses a native node module (node-snowball) that requires compilation to run. as I am running macOS the compiled code that runs on my local machine will not run in AWS Lambda's Amazon Linux environment. For that reason I am using Docker and the [`lambci/lambda:build-nodejs8.10`](https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/) IMAGE to compile to code that will run on Lambda which I then deploy via Serverless.

**Problem**

Inside my project directory with the compiled for mac node modules installed, I run the container with the following command.

```
# To compile native deps in node_modules (runs `npm rebuild`)
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/var/task lambci/lambda:build-nodejs8.10
```

9/10 times the compilation step completes successfully but then errors out on the `node postinstall` step with an `ENOENT` error looking for serverless (full output below).

```
> node-snowball@0.2.0 install /var/task/node_modules/node-snowball
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/var/task/node_modules/node-snowball/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/snowball/src/snowball.o
  ...
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/snowball/src/libstemmer/src_c/stem_UTF_8_turkish.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/snowball.node
  COPY Release/snowball.node
make: Leaving directory `/var/task/node_modules/node-snowball/build'

> spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall /var/task/node_modules/spawn-sync
> node postinstall

npm ERR! path /var/task/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/var/task/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-02-21T11_46_54_327Z-debug.log
```

However looking in my project directory I can see the serverless files are there.

```
my-app-directory/
|__node_modules/
   |__serverless/
      |__bin/
         |__serverless
```

What makes this more confusing is that 1/10 times the operation will complete successfully without throwing any errors (output below).

```
> node-snowball@0.2.0 install /var/task/node_modules/node-snowball
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/var/task/node_modules/node-snowball/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/snowball/src/snowball.o
  ...
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/snowball/src/libstemmer/src_c/stem_UTF_8_turkish.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/snowball.node
  COPY Release/snowball.node
make: Leaving directory `/var/task/node_modules/node-snowball/build'

> spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall /var/task/node_modules/spawn-sync
> node postinstall


> serverless@1.37.1 postinstall /var/task/node_modules/serverless
> node ./scripts/postinstall.js

aws-sdk@2.404.0 /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk
...
serverless@1.37.1 /var/task/node_modules/serverless
async@1.5.2 /var/task/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/async
raven@1.2.1 /var/task/node_modules/raven
uuid@3.0.0 /var/task/node_modules/raven/node_modules/uuid
uuid@2.0.3 /var/task/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/uuid
```

What could be causing this inconsistent behaviour and how can I fix it?

Comment: I am seeing the same thing. It doesn't make sense to me since the directory `/var/task/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless` appears to be there, so not sure why the chmod is returning ENOENT. In my case it seems to always fail.

Comment: I wonder if it could be a race condition if for you it seems to work some of the time. I wouldn't expect this directory to be deleted and recreated though, so not sure what is happening.

Comment: In my case I am not using snowball but parquetjs which has a binary extension lzo which needs to be recompiled. lzo rebuild succeeds, but the spawn-sync fails with the chmod ENOENT

Comment: I think either upgrading tabtab so its dependencies don't use spawn-sync (node 8+ already have spawn and don't need the polyfill) or making the autocomplete functionality a plugin or manually installed via command would solve our problems. 

https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4069

Comment: I created a quick and dirty fork of serverless without autocompletion (tabtab) to see if it would work. It seems to solve the problem. https://github.com/jeffbski/serverless/tree/remove-tabtab-autocompletion

Comment: I created this PR to remove autocomplete (and tabtab) from core serverless. https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/5875

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution until serverless removes the autocomplete (tabtab) dependency is to run your docker command to only rebuild the modules that need it instead of the default which rebuilds them all.

So in your case if you just need node-snowball rebuilt you could use this command

```sh
# only rebuild node-snowball
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/var/task lambci/lambda:build-nodejs8.10 npm rebuild node-snowball
```

Comment: Ah of course, I should have thought of that! I still don't really understand what `tabtab` was doing that made it inconsistent but good to have a solution. Nice one on the PR.